# Графическая характеристика последовательности

Tags: c++

Нужно сгенерировать случайные числа и затем сохранить в файл графическую характеристику последовательности этих чисел, используя распределение на плоскости (элементы попарно обрабатываются, как координаты точек (x,y)). Вопрос: как можно реализовать такую графическую характеристику?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "Графическая характеристика последовательности" ?

Comment: @Kromster Единственное, что сказано в задании- это элементы попарно обрабатываются как  как координаты точек (x,y)

Comment: Почему Вы не уточните у того человка, который дал Вам задание, что он под этим понимает?

Comment: Генерировать надо очень много чисел. И в процессе стройте трёхмерную гистограмму например. Можно цветовую карту (как географическая карта высот), высота накапливается в зависимости от количества попаданий пар в каждую точку карты.

Comment: И да! Дабы не строить слишком большую карту, можно группировать соседние попадания округлением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятнее всего под графической характеристикой в данном задании понимаетеся то, как будут распределены точки на плоскости. Причём подразумевается, что вы генерируете пары чисел.

Пример.

```
vector<Pair<float, float>> vec;

for i = 0; i < n; ++i {
    vec.push(Pair{first: rand(), second: rand()})
}

// save vec to file
```

Comment: ну вообщето лучше ещё и счётчик тудой забацать... вдруг повторы будут?

Comment: И что же, что будут повторы?

Comment: можно вообще с другого конца подойти, и наоборот квадрат счётчиков сделать, а точки в него вписывать и инкрементить нужный счётчик.

Comment: ибо характеристика не только в рисунке, но и в рамномерности

Comment: Квадрат счётчика? Вы о чём? Нулевой счётчик? Равномерность? Что за набор терминов?

Comment: скажите спасибо что ещё кореляцию по этой хрени не считаем ;)

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы умничать, лучше бы что-нибудь дельное сказали бы ;)

Comment: не обижайся, я не специально.